# Cannot get images to overlap

Tags: html, css, stellar.js

I'm building a photo gallery using Stellar.js, and it gets tricky to make images overlap (just a simple parallax effect, that said).

Here's the link:
http://foalenraged.com/david/indexi.php

Here's the way I would like it to work:
http://markpeckmezian.com/

Divs are generated using PHP:

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++){
                $rand = rand(1, 20);
                $rand = $rand/10;
                $margin = -1*(1500-($i*100));
                echo '<div id="image'.$i.'" data-stellar-ratio="'.$rand.'" data-stellar-vertical-offset="'.$margin.'" style="z-index: '.$i.'; width="10%"><img src="'.$dir."/".$files[$i].'"></div>
                ';


            }
```

Comment: Can you add code and / or images to your question? If your code of the site change, it's not a good question anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm speaking about mouvement bug, thus cannot add informative images. Will add some code though